# Automatic Type conversion of row vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Say I have a row vector defined as follows:

```
x = [5 6.7 8.9]
```

The above code results in a row vector with all the elements being typecasted as floating points(including the 5 in the 1st index).

```
x =

   5.0000   6.7000   8.9000
```

Is there any way I can prevent the typecasting of the 5 (present in the first place), i.e. is there any way I can get my vector as follows:

```
x =

   5  6.7000   8.9000
```

without the four decimal points after the **5**.

Comment: All entries of a vector have to be of the same type. Anyway, the floating-point `double` data type includes integers up to magnitude `2^53`, so it shouldn't be a problem. That `4.0000` you see is the same value (albeit in a different data type) than say `uint32(4)`

Comment: You can't do that with a normal array, but you can with a *cell* array. Interestingly, if I create a cell array in Octave like `x = {5 6.7 8.9}`, the `5` is *displayed* without the decimal point, but its class is still `double`.

Comment: do you care only for the visual here or the actual type conversion?

Comment: @bla beaker has already answered without preserving the type. So, I'd much appreciate a snippet that doesn't change the type while keeping the visuals.

Comment: @AdityaSaini `x = {int32(5) 6.7 8.9}` (or whatever integer type you want) will create a cell array with one integer and two doubles, if that's what you're looking for. Or you could create a struct. Or two separate arrays. Lots of options.

Comment: NB: Using cell arrays (`{...}`) here might get you what you want in terms of display formatting, but in general, using cells means your performance is going to be Bad. Stick with numerics if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Matlab and Octave, `double` is the default value for all numeric values, even if some of those values might be whole numbers (integers). And for numeric arrays, all elements must be of the same type.

In general, you should just leave all your numeric values as doubles, and use formatting controls (like those provided by `printf()` and its friends) to display them how you want.

In this case, you could do something like:

```matlab
x = [5 6.7 8.9];
printf('%d  %.04f  %.04f\n', x);
```

Or to be more flexible:

```
printf('%g  ', x); printf('\n');
```